# jQuery's fadeIn and fadeOut doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've got HTML:

```js
var $button = $('#trigger');
     var $to_top = $('#to_top');
     $button.on('click', function() {
      $to_top.slideToggle();
     });
```

```css
#to_top {
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 20px;
     right: 20px;
     background-color: #9B9EA0;
     float: right;
     width: 56px;
     height: 56px;
     fill: white;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="to_top">
     <svg>
      <path d="M16.652 37.273l13.102-12.045L42.86 37.273l3.796-2.563-16.902-15.534L12.858 34.71"/>
     </svg>
    </div>
    <button id="trigger">FadeIt</button>
```

The problem is that when I'm clicking the button nothing happens. What's wrong with my code.

Comment: See your question now and tell what isn't working?

Comment: I think, you needed Jquery library reference. that @kittyCat added

Comment: Yeah.... But on my site it's not working and nothing appears in my console.

Comment: Did you add it right before `</body>`

Comment: jQuery referenced on my page and it works on other pages.

Comment: Functions like hide() works normally.

Comment: is this your problem?

Comment: @simon, your problem solved?

Comment: Oh, thanks everyone, I've realize where the problem was! Into another js file the function animate was overwritten that's why it's didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, please note you are using a slide effect not fade.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $button = $('#trigger');
    var $to_top = $('#to_top');
    $button.on('click', function() {
        $to_top.slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included inside $( window ).load(function() { ... }) will run once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  //Your code here
});
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer].